# Ajax select picker doesn’t sense

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I put it in the option it doesn't work. So I thought about opening inspect ekementos and testing the title="" in some places. I realized that a list was being created outside the select  and

and if I put the title in them, it works. My question is how do I operate this list, since I don't have any of this in my code?
 `Aplicacao.ExibeCarregando(); var elem = TipoDado(tipoDadoId, campoPersonalizado, mascara); dVValorFiltro.empt`y().append(elem.html);```your text``
if (tipoDadoId != 5) {
Aplicacao.Mascaras();
}

```
    if (tipoDadoId == 5) {
        var slValorFiltro = jQuery('#valor-filtro');
        var optns = '<option value="" selected>' + CRMElementoSelectOptionSelecione + '</option>';
        var tipoRegistroId = TipoRegistro;
        var ret = BuscarValoresAtributoOperador(tipoRegistroId, atributoId, operadorId, tipoFiltro, campoPersonalizado);
        if (DadosConsulta.AtributoValores == null) {
            DadosConsulta.AtributoValores = [];
        }
        ret.success(function (r) {
            DadosConsulta.AtributoValores.push({
                AtributoId: atributoId,
                Valores: r
            });
            var itens = r;
            var gr = null;
            var fechar = false;
            var idx = 0;
            var textToInsert = [];
            if (valorSelecionadoFiltro && valorSelecionadoFiltro.length > 0) {
                textToInsert[idx++] = '<option value="" >' + CRMElementoSelectOptionSelecione + '</option>';
            }
            else {
                textToInsert[idx++] = '<option value="" selected >' + CRMElementoSelectOptionSelecione + '</option>';
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
                if (valorSelecionadoFiltro && valorSelecionadoFiltro == itens[i].nome) {
                    textToInsert[idx++] = '<option selected data-valorId="' + itens[i].valorId + '" value="' + itens[i].id + '">' + itens[i].nome + '</option>';
                }
                else {
                    textToInsert[idx++] = '<option data-valorId="' + itens[i].valorId + '" value="' + itens[i].id + '">' + itens[i].nome + '</option>';
                }
            }
            valorSelecionadoFiltro = null;
            dvValorNovoFiltro.show();
            btnExecutarFiltro.show();
            spnTotalFiltro.html('').hide();
            btnInserirFiltro.hide();
            //slValorFiltro.empty().append(textToInsert.join('')).selectpicker('refresh');
            try {
                slValorFiltro.empty().append(textToInsert.join('')).selectpicker().ajaxSelectPicker({
                    ajax: {
                        url: '/Atributo/ListarValor',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            q: '{{{q}}}',
                            tipoRegistroId: tipoRegistroId,
                            atributoId: atributoId,
                            operadorId: operadorId,
                            campoPersonalizado: campoPersonalizado
                        },
                        success: function (r) {
                            DadosConsulta.AtributoValores.push({
                                AtributoId: atributoId,
                                Valores: r
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    emptyRequest: true,
                    clearOnEmpty: false,
                    preserveSelected: false,
                    log: 0,
                    templates: '',
                    locale: {
                        currentlySelected: CRMEMKTLabelCurrentlySelected, //'Currently Selected'
                        emptyTitle: CRMEMKTLabelEmptyTitle, //'Select and begin typing'
                        errorText: CRMEMKTLabelErrorText, //'Unable to retrieve results',
                        searchPlaceholder: CRMEMKTLabelSearchPlaceholder, //'Search...',
                        statusInitialized: CRMEMKTLabelStatusInitialized, //'Start typing a search query',
                        statusNoResults: CRMEMKTLabelStatusNoResults, //'No Results',
                        statusSearching: CRMEMKTLabelStatusSearching, //'Searching...',
                        statusTooShort: CRMEMKTLabelStatusTooShort, //'Please enter more characters'
                    },
                    preprocessData: function (data) {
                        var array = [];
                        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                try {
                                    array.push($.extend(true, data[i], {
                                        text: data[i].nome,
                                        value: data[i].id,
                                        data: {
                                            valorId: data[i].valorId
                                        }
                                    }));
                                } catch (e) {
                                    console.log(e.message);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return array;
                    }
                });
                slValorFiltro.selectpicker('refresh');
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
            slValorFiltro.change(function () {
                btnInserirFiltro.hide();
                spnTotalFiltro.html('').hide();
            });                  
            jQuery('#dv-valor-filtro button').focus();
            Aplicacao.RemoveCarregando();

        }).error(function (requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
            console.log(requestObject);
            console.log(error);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            Aplicacao.RemoveCarregando();
        });
    }
    else {
        dvValorNovoFiltro.show();
        btnExecutarFiltro.show();
        spnTotalFiltro.html('').hide();
        btnInserirFiltro.hide();
        jQuery('#dv-valor-filtro .sl-filtro').focus();
        Aplicacao.RemoveCarregando();
    }
}`
```

I can't manipulate the list using ajax select picker.

Comment: The JavaScript code seems malformed or incomplete. It might help to provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.